# Spring Integration - HTTP gateway and JMS

Tags: jms, spring-integration

I have a requirement where client sends an HTTP requests, our application processes it and generates response and sends back the HTTP response.  The request and response need to be persisted on JMS queues.  In order for us to leverage Spring integration in this scenario, can we use spring integration HTTP gateways in place of our current MVC controllers ?  Would I need separate gateways for each different uri mapping ?  Can the HTTP gateway be integrated with JMS channels ?  I would appreciate some ideas on the high level architecture using Spring Integration for this scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest on-ramp would probably to inject a [Messaging Gateway](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) (`<gateway/>`) into your existing controller; if you are simply archiving the request/response, you just need a simply gateway method that returns void and in the Spring Integration flow, wire the `<gateway/>` to a `<jms:outbound-channel-adapter/>`.

Comment: Thanks Gary.  However, let's say the requirement is to replace the MVC controllers with the HTTP gateways, would it be still possible to integrate them with the JMS channels or would I still require the jms:outbound-channel adapter ?   And also, how to map multiple urls within the same gateway definition ?

Comment: Yes, you can replace your controllers with gateways; you cannot currently map multiple URLs to the same gateway, but multiple gateways can feed messages into the same channel. You would typically not use jms-backed channels for this; they are generally used to provide persistence at points within an SI flow. For inter-process communication (or general JMS activity) you would usually use channel adapters instead.